# Getting error at shipping step on checkoutpage in Magento after installing SSL

Tags: magento, ssl

After installing the SSL on a Magento site, the checkout page has stopped working after the shipping method. It's not able to load the next step.

I am not getting any specific error but its not loading the next step. When I tried to look it in to ajax call, POST was completed successfully but not able to complete the GET request to update the right side and load the payment method (next step). It was working fine before we have installed the SSL.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you need to increase the amount of ram assigned to the site.